# Got to page on pageable list view Wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm using a pagableListView inside Wicket with a pagenavigator, and sometimes my search result can return 1,000's of pages. This can be tedious for the user to navigate through each page to get to the middle of the alphabet. Is there a way I can create some sort of go to page:    functionality?  This way the user can say eh, like try page 600 see where I am at.. instead of meticulously clicking  a bunch of times to get there.

Thanks!

Comment: WHy dont you add a search filter for name or what you have there that starts with characters?

Comment: Please, post full code and markup.

Comment: Simply write your own Component that sets the currentPage of your Pageable (like PageListView).